# Using null coalescing in foreach statement

Tags: c#, null, foreach, null-coalescing-operator

Trying to figure out how to get the null coalescing operator to work in a foreach loop.

I'm checking to see what a string ends with and based on that, route it to a certain method. Basically what I want to say is....

```
foreach (String s in strList)
{
    if s.EndsWith("d") ?? Method1(s) ?? Method2(s) ?? "Unknown file type";
}
```

In attempting to do this, of course you get the "Operator ?? cannot be used on type bool and type string." I know there is other ways to do it, just want to see how it can be done with null coalescing.

Have a good weekend.

@Richard Ev: Oh yes of course. Switch, if else, etc. Was just curious how it
could be handled

@Jon Skeet: After reading your comments it hit me, this is just bad! I am
interested in two file extensions basically. If a file ends with "abc" for
instance, send to method 1, if the file ends with "xyz" send to method 2. But
what if a file ends with an extension of "hij"...boom, you're done.

Thanks to Brian and GenericTypeTea as well for the thoughful input

I'm content calling it closed.

Comment: Do **what** with a null-coalescing operator? Your example doesn't make sense. What is it meant to do?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do. If you could write it in a different way (but with valid code) we might be able to help. We've no idea what Method1 or Method2 do, or what you want to do with the string "Unknown file type".

Comment: It's important to note that you are not assigning the result of that statement to anything. Currently what you have will either evaluate to the return type of Method1 or the return type of method 2, or the string "unknown file type", but you are not doing anything with that result. Somewhere there needs to be an assignment to a variable.

Comment: I think that other developers in your team would rather you write slightly more verbose, but readable code, than try to shoehorn things like the `??` operator into situations where it doesn't really add value.

Comment: `s.EndsWith()` will return _only_ a true or false, never a null. The null coalescing operator only works when an operand has the potential to be null. Therefore, you won't be able to use the null coalescing operator with the EndsWith boolean.

Comment: Why not accept one of the answers from your other question (over a year ago)? You had some good responses and it might draw more interest in future questions. Personally, I could care less, but it does seem to be a motivating factor for others on SO.

Comment: The "foreach" loop has nothing to do with it. It would help if you'd write out using "if" statements what you want this to do, and then we'll see if there's a more compact way to write it. This code as it stands does not make enough sense to figure out what you're going for.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you want to use the normal ternary operator, not null coalescing. Something like:

```
(s.EndsWith("d") ? Method1(s) : Method2(s)) ?? "Unknown file type";
```

This is equivalent to:

```
string result;
if (s.EndsWith("d"))
  result = Method1(s);
else
  result = Method2(s);
if (result == null)
  result = "Unknown file type";
return result;
```

Comment: This would depend on Method1 and Method2 both being able to return a null (i.e., ref types not value types)

Comment: @Funka, the result type of the `??` operator is a `string` so I think it's safe for Bob to assume that `Method1` and `Method2` are also returning a `string`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a combination of the conditional (ternary) operator and the null coalescing operator:

```
foreach (String s in strList)
{
    string result = (s.EndsWith("d") ? Method1(s) : Method2(s)) 
        ?? "Unknown file type";
}
```

In simple english, this will do the following:

```
If s ends with d, then it will try Method1.
If s does not end with d then it will try Method2.
Then if the outcome is null, it will use "Unknown file type"
If the outcome is not null, it will use the result of either A or B
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler gave you the appropriate answer, you can't.

Null coalescing is essentially this if statement:

```
if(x == null)
  DoY();
else
  DoZ();
```

A boolean value cannot be null, so you can't coalesce it like that.  I'm not sure what your other methods return, but it seems like you want a simple `||` operator here.

Answer (score 0):

You should first use the `??` null coalescing operator to guard against a null `s` reference. Then use the `?` ternary operator to choose between `Method1` and `Method2`. Finally use the `??` null coalescing operator again to provide the default value.

```
foreach (string s in strList)
{
    string computed = s;
    computed = computed ?? String.Empty;
    computed = computed.EndsWith("d") ? Method1(s) : Method2(s);
    computed = computed ?? "Unknown file type";
}
```